# How to uninstall gitlab from local ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

How do I uninstall gitlab?

I deleted the `/home/gitlab` directory but it still opens up when I browse to my hostname.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Stop the gitlab service. Try doing.

```
sudo apt-get remove gitlab-ce
```

Then remove gitlab files from the system. Some files are in */etc* directory.

Have a look at the official documentation.

Comment: i did this but no luck i still can open gitlab login page !! no i'm trying this:

Comment: Kill all processes
    run uninstall
    Delete all files / directory
    Reboot
i'm waiting until the reboot finish

Comment: Not very funny, but you should hard reboot your server to not every running process

Answer (score 55):

This worked on ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get remove gitlab-ce

sudo rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab
```

--kill all process live

```
sudo pkill -f gitlab
```

-- Remove paths

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/gitlab

sudo rm -rf /etc/gitlab

rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab
```

Comment: All of those commands have to be run with sudo and you need to add `sudo rm -rf /etc/gitlab-runner`. Then too `sudo rm -rf /opt/gitlab` produces the comical error `rm: cannot remove '/opt/gitlab/sv/redis/log/supervise': Directory not empty`. I resorted to `sudo nautilus`, the file-finder GUI for that one.

Comment: Works also on Ubuntu **20.04**

Comment: add " sudo apt purge gitlab-ce -y" . >> work in ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 16):

uninstall Gitlab:

1-  Stop the gitlab service

Command : `sudo gitlab-ctl stop`

2-  Start commonde of service facility

command : `sudo gitlab-ctl uninstall`

3-  Delete the package of gitlab

command : Locat *gitlab*

4- restart machine